# How to abandon a request and not have to respond to it?

Tags: django, response, render-to-response

There are some bots that just keep hitting my site over and over again.

```
http://proxy.parser.by/proxy.php (Referrer)
```

I don't want to even reply to anyone that is requesting a .php, or .htm, or .html file.

What is the best way of not responding to such requests?

Update: (I don't want to incur the cost of responding)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably best done at the server level, before the request even gets to Django. For example, in Apache, you can use `mod_rewrite` for access control. This rule rejects all requests with paths ending with `.php`, `.htm`, or `.html`:

```
RewriteRule \.(php|html?)$ - [F]
```

The [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/access.html) explains how to block requests by user agent, by referer, by orginating IP address, and so on.

Comment: I don't want to reply at all.

Comment: Then I think you need a firewall. Not an area I know much about, but maybe take a look at [ModSecurity](http://www.modsecurity.org/)? But the [Apache wiki says](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ProxyAbuse) "the savings in resource usage [from dropping requests instead of rejecting them] will be minuscule"

Answer (score 0):

Drop in some middleware which will detect any request you don't want to handle and have it return an HTTP 403 (Forbidden).